# Unable to click my mouse from C/C++ code

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to control my mouse through key board. For this I use two header files :-

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

to get current position I called

```
POINT p;
GetCursorPos(&p);
```

To move my cursor on right I call

```
 p.x += 10;
```

And to move my cursor on all other direction I use method just like above.Till now every thing is fine. But I don't know how to left-click my mouse from my code. So please tell me any way to do that

Comment: PostMessage(...,WM_LBUTTONDOWN,...)

Comment: "I can't figure out how to left-click my mouse from my code" is a problem we can't fix because we don't actually know what is wrong without looking at the error code. Aslo what is your question? @huseyintugrulbuyukisik How is your comment helpful in fixing his cursor?

Comment: Actually I don't know what function should be call for clicking left button of mouse

Comment: @bot he will search and learn how to use postmessage to simulate clicking using keyboard

Comment: A mouse is an input device, your read it rather than control it, and you cannot click it in code - you use your finger! ;-)

Comment: @Clifford - you could control an electromechanical servo to... oh, never mind.

Comment: @MartinJames : And you can insert events in the input buffer to simulate a mouse click, which from the OP's own answer appears to be exactly what he wanted.

Comment: The real question behind all questions asking to simulate input is: How do I automate my UI? And the answer to all those questions is: [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer, here is the function for left-click:-

```
void LeftClick ( )
{  
  INPUT    Input={0};
  // left down 
  Input.type      = INPUT_MOUSE;
  Input.mi.dwFlags  = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
  ::SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));

  // left up
  ::ZeroMemory(&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
  Input.type      = INPUT_MOUSE;
  Input.mi.dwFlags  = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
  ::SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

Any way thanks guys for your help.

Comment: The whole point of using [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) is to prevent synthesized input from getting interspersed with input generated from other sources. Calling it twice in a row with a one-sized array amounts to completely missing the point. This is explicitly spelled out in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In a Win32 console application, the mouse state can be read via [ReadConsoleInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961(v=vs.85).aspx).  It fills an array of [INPUT_RECORD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683499(v=vs.85).aspx) structures, that contains amongst other things mouse status.

Here is an example of its use: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/05/06/10416225.aspx

Note that as a low-level console I/O command, it may interfere with higher level I/O such as conio or stdio.  You should process all your console I/O via this function to avoid that perhaps?